# HTML link automatically highlighting itself as soon as page is loaded

Tags: javascript, css, html, hyperlink, highlight

I'm quite proud of myself. I'm working on my 1st website & I've just created my 1st html link using the "a" tag :D Thee ONLY problem I seem to be having at this point is that every time I open up my webpage, the link is ALREADY highlighted. I don't have to click on it, or drag the cursor over it, or anything. How do I make it so that it only highlights once you drag the cursor over it? Any help would be very much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

<title>Round Table</title>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="RTH.css">
<script src="RTH.js"></script>

</head>

<body>


<H1> Come & take a seat at the Round Table B] </H1> 

<p> "Where <i>REAL MUSIC</i> still exists"</p><br><br>

<ol type=I> <H2> <li>BEAT$</li> 
<br><li>Music by Mercile$$</li> 
<br><li>Spoken Word</li> <br>
<li><a href="RthPg2.html" title="RthPg2">Tale$ of a Blind Sword$man</a></li> </H2> </ol><br><br><br>

<dt><i>RTH</i> consists of:</dt> 
<dd>Show Luciano, Pistol McFly, Dior, YZ, & last but not least...Mercile$$</dd>

<p> thee music industry is DEAD !! i hope to bring restoration.<br>

                                                                                            ~mercile$$</p><br>

<footer>&copy; Round Table</footer>
</font>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
body {
        background-image: url("Round Table, Hoe II.jpg");
    background-repeat: Repeat;
    font-family: AR Christy, Kozuka Gothic Pr6N, Cooper std;
    color: Red;
    text-shadow: 1px 0 0 #CEA40C, 0 -1px 0 #CEA40C, 0 1px 0 #CEA40C, -1px 0 0 #CEA40C;
        font-size: 25px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 700px;

}

h1 {
    font-family: AR Christy, Kozuka Gothic Pr6N, Cooper std;
    color: Red;
    text-shadow: 2px 0 0 #CEA40C, 0 0px 0 #CEA40C, 0 2px 0 #CEA40C, 0px 0 0 #CEA40C;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
    width: 700px;

}

i {
    font-family: AR Christy, Kozuka Gothic Pr6N, Cooper std;
    color: White;
    text-shadow: 2px 0 0 #CEA40C, 0 0px 0 #CEA40C, 0 2px 0 #CEA40C, 0px 0 0 #CEA40C;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
    width: 700px;

}

dt {

    color: #1BD29B;
    text-shadow: 4px 0 0 #CEA40C, 0 0px 0 #CEA40C, 0 4px 0 #CEA40C, 0px 0 0 #CEA40C;
    font-size: 45pt;
    padding: 10px;


}

dd {

    color: White;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px; 
    background: #f03; 
    border: solid 2px #fff;

}

p {
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px; 
    background: #f03; 
    border: solid 2px #fff; 

}

footer {



}
```

I haven't created the .js file yet...

Comment: you made only one properties in css for link (a) so it is always the same. Apply different styles for a:hover,a:visited ...

Comment: What do you mean by “highlighted”? Please be specific, and specify also the browser(s) tested.

Answer (score 1):

you can use css selectors for any of anchor states

```
a, a:visited, a:active {
     text-decoration: none;
     color: inherit; // from parent element
}
a:hover, a.highlighted {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: blue;
    // anything you want
}
```

then use jquery to add specific class on hover

```
$('a').hover(
    function () {
        $(this).addClass('highlighted');
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks! Came out even better than I had hoped :D

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your CSS to make your links look like the rest of the content and highlight itself (underline) only when hovered over.

```
a {
    ...
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}

a:hover {
    ...
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}
```